# Disable Winreg Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-3.4

I work with the IT Technicians and they have asked me to look into disabling the module winreg/_winreg. However, after a few hours or so of searching, I was unable to find anything that would work.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

We need to remove the winreg module, as it allows the students to bypass all of the security software put in place to stop students from breaking the servers.

Comment: Disabling a module? What does that even mean? You need to edit your question @Kamg300 and further elaborate and what you mean.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to disable [**`winreg`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html)?

Comment: `_winreg` is builtin to Python 2.7.

Comment: Disabling the module won't fix the security issue you're having. The student could simply use a plethora of other tools to edit the window's registry. This simply "pythonizes" the windows registry api. Lock down the machine so they don't have access to "break" the servers with simple registry edits.